# Input value to be in percentage and not in pixel?

Tags: php

I'm using a plugin for a WordPress site to embed a 3d view from sketchfab.

This plugin has options to set/determine the width and height of the iframe of this 3d model.

My issue here is that I want to put a value in % and not in PX as I want it to be full width ( an all devices ).

The link to the plugin is this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/sketchfab-viewer/

```
 <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row">Width</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="sketchfab-width" value="<?php echo get_option('sketchfab-width'); ?>" />px</td>
 </tr>
```

This is the code for the input field.

Can anybody save the day for me?

I'm a novice in this as you might have already noticed.

Thanks! :)

Comment: get value of `get_option('sketchfab-width');` store it in a variable and apply calculations to it to convert to percent?

Comment: Would save the day for you mean: Someone maintans that Wordpress plugin in such a manner to add an option use a CSS percentage next to the CSS length in pixels for you?

Comment: @sietse85 maybe I'm wrong but there is no calculation in correct conversion of px into % as px is an absolute value and % is not. Maybe I'm wrong as I'm not really sure :/ that's why I need a bit of help with this.

Comment: @hakre anything will do the job, if the iframe i'm embeding will show at 100% width on any screen! :)

Comment: @xake: Why don't you hack the output and replace px in the output of that value with %? Should do it, only the entry-field then might look misleading, but you can hack that as well. Just search the plugins files for "px".

Comment: @hakre well that might be easy for you but i'm kinda a novice in this, soo yeah :D Show me how please?.

Comment: Sure, I would as next take a look into the documentation of the computer system I'm using to learn about how to search through files inside a directory and then I would search for "px" in the folder of the Wordpress plugin.

Comment: I can change the PX into %. That's not the problem, what I meant was to hack the output.

Comment: change it there as well. It's only text.

Comment: @hakre i did do that previously and I then added 100 to the input field but the output was 100px even though I changed the px to %

Comment: well you need to remove the "px" from the output and replace it with "%". If the output still shows "px" that's not done yet (or something got cached, perhaps disabling cache in Wordpress for your development helps?!).

Comment: it appears that it didn't need me to do anything just add the full 100% as a value into it and it would work.